# Difference in peak dB value between sound forge spectrum analysis and Welch Sectrogram using python

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, psd, spectrum

Using welch Average spectrum for the audio signal using `scipy.signal.welch()` function python. I am verifying the same using the Sound forge spectrum analysis. Peak values between the python code and sound forge is not matching. I am getting the difference of 10 db. that is with python code i am getting 10 db lee when compare to sound forge tool.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Function used to compute the spectrum analysis in python.

```
scipy.signal.welch(x, fs=1.0, window='hanning', nperseg=256, noverlap=None, nfft=None, detrend='constant', return_onesided=True, scaling='density', axis=-1)
```

when I compute the peak value of spectrum obtained from above function I am getting 10db less than soundforge value.

Comment: This might be a better fit on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, I'd suggest posting there if you don't get an answer here within an hour or so.

Comment: A dB value is a relative value, not an absolute value - there’s an implicit reference value. Without any further information I’d guess that the two methods have different implicit reference values.